# Loading text and images via cross domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I'm loading a page from a remote server to my local computer which has an image called from a database table and some text on the page , i'm loading the page via ajax with a cross domain script in my `web.config` file. the text on the page is able to load correctly into the div but not the image. the path to call the image is correctly mapped

```
<script language="javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

$('#load').load('http://example/some1.asp');

    });

</script>
```

Comment: in browser dev tools inspect the live html for clues. Nothing shown in question would tell us why you don't see image

Comment: thanks, i did that and i'm able to track the error and solved it.